# How do I finish the puzzle in Just A Little Bit Shy?

Tags: antichamber

The puzzle in *Just a Little Bit Shy* involves moving yellow blocks to interrupt lasers. I have tried this puzzle several times and it seems clear that there are not enough yellow blocks to open the door. In the picture below, every yellow block is covering a laser and the door is still not open. What do I have to do to solve this?

[image: Block puzzle]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Huh, maybe you found an alternate way/method to get into the red gun room, because part of the answer to that one was very similar to the answer to this one.

The mechanic you use:

> Remember how making an outline of a rectangle with blocks causes the outline to fill in?

Do that, around the center area, by dragging the yellow blocks. It should generate four blocks each time you do it.

Repeating this procedure a couple of times will give you enough yellow blocks to interrupt all of the lasers.

Minor extra spoiler:

> Note that you don't have to manually block all of the lasers; if you make one big outline around the outside edge of the box, the yellow blocks will fill in and block all the lasers for you.

Comment: Oh man, I assumed for the entire time that the rectangles would only fill in if I was actively placing blocks into the area.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Assuming makes an ass out of U and some poor kid named Ming. Please, think of Ming!

Comment: Yellow blocks disappear when I try to move them into some positions with the yellow gun. Why?